# Find the derivative of the function $y=5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $y=5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$

Is there a faster way to find the derivative for this function?

Comment: Faster than what? You haven't proposed a solution or method. Also, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How do you use mathjax?

Answer (score 2):

Find the derivative: $y=5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$

Although this particular problem is fairly straightforward using the product rule, when three or more factors are involved you might want to know about logarithmic differentiation.

Take $\ln$ of both sides to get

$$ \ln y=\ln5+2\ln(x+3)+5\ln(2x-1) $$

Take the derivative of both sides to get

$$ \frac{y^\prime}{y}=\frac{2}{x+3}+\frac{10}{2x-1}$$

Multiply on the left by $y$ and on the right by $5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$ to get

$$ y^\prime = \left(\frac{2}{x+3}+\frac{10}{2x-1}\right)\cdot5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$$

This may be taken further

$$ y^\prime = 10(x+3)(2x-1)^5+ 50(x+3)^2(2x-1)^4$$

factored

$$ y^\prime =10(x+3)(2x-1)^4[\,(2x-1)+5(x+3)\,] $$

and simplified to obtain a completely factor answer

$$ y^\prime = 10(x+3)(2x-1)^4(7x+14)$$

$$ y^\prime = 70(x+3)(2x-1)^4(x+2)$$

Comment: The only legitimately simple answer here. +1

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$y'=10(x+3)(2x-1)^5+50(x+3)^2(2x-1)^4=70(x+3)(2x-1)^4(x+2)$

Comment: I try following the product rule, then I get lost in the middle of it.

Comment: I have trouble getting to that part 10(x+3)(2x-1)^5+50(x+3)^2(2x-1)^4

Comment: @Fiona Lu It's just $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the problem, I wasn't getting the right derivative for (2x-1)^5

Comment: @Fiona Lu You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use product rule.

(uv) = uv' + u'v

$y=5(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5$

$y=5\left[(x+3)^2(2x-1)^5\right]$

$y'=5\left[(x+3)^2 \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(2x-1)^5 + \frac{d}{dx}(x+3)^2 \cdot (2x-1)^5\right]$

$=5\left[(x+3)^2 \cdot 5(2x-1)^{5-1}\frac{d}{dx}(2x-1)+ 2(x+3)^{2-1}\frac{d}{dx}(x+3) \cdot (2x-1)^5\right]$

$=5\left[(x+3)^2 \cdot 5(2x-1)^4 \cdot 2+ 2(x+3)^1 \cdot 1 \cdot (2x-1)^5 \right]$

Hope you can proceed further.

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)